# R/Shiny - How to write a .csv reactively including a actionButton?

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I am trying to figure out how to write a .csv based on selections made by the end user. The selections made will subset the "geodata.csv" and write a separate "solution.csv" file in the application folder.

**N.B.** - I have created a [github repo](https://github.com/ucg8j/ShinyWriteCsv) to make solving the question easier. It contains the geodata.csv, ui.R & server.R but no solution.csv yet!

**geodata.csv**

```
Postcode,HC,BSL,Position Location
10,1,A,C
10,1,A,D
10,1,A,D
11,1,B,C
11,1,B,C
```

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(
 pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Min. working example - write a csv based on user input'),

  sidebarPanel(
   selectInput("filter1", "First selection:" 
              , choices = c(Choose='', "A", "B")
              #, multiple=T
              ),

   selectInput("filter2", "Second selection:", 
              choices = c(Choose='', "C", "D")
              ),
   br(),
   p("Include actionButton to prevent write occuring before user finalises selection"),  
   actionButton("generateButton","Write Data")    
  ),
  mainPanel()
 )
)
```

**server.R**

```
# Load data
setwd("/Users/lukesingham/SOtestApp")
geodata <- read.csv("geodata.csv", na.string = "#N/A", row.names=NULL)

# Reactivity to subset data ####
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  geodatasetInput <- reactive({

    # BSL switch
    selection <-switch(input$BSL
                       , A = "A"
                       , B = "B"
                       ) 
    # Location switch    
    selection2 <-switch(input$Location
                       , C = "C"
                       , D = "D"
                       )

    # subset based on selection
    Subgeodata <- subset(geodata, BSL == selection & Position.Location == selection2)

    # Execute selections on data upon button-press
    input$generateButton

    # aggregate by postcode
    Subgeodata <- Subgeodata[1:2] #no longer need other columns
    AggSubGdata <- aggregate(. ~ Postcode, data=Subgeodata, FUN=sum)
    isolate(write.csv(AggSubGdata
              , file = "/Users/lukesingham/SOtestApp/solution.csv"
              , row.names=F
    ))
  })
})
```

**solution.csv**

For example, based on user selections of `A` and `D` the solution file should look like this:

```
Postcode,HC
10,2
```

Comment: `downloadButton` might be a better choice rather than `actionButton` in your case

Comment: I don't actually want to give the option to the end user of downloading the file. The .csv created here becomes a dependency in a bigger shiny application not included here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the working example:

```
# Load data
setwd("/Users/lukesingham/SOtestApp")
geodata <- read.csv("geodata.csv", na.string = "#N/A", row.names=NULL)

# Reactivity to subset data ####
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  geodatasetInput <- observe({

    # Execute selections on data upon button-press
    if(input$generateButton == 0) return()

    inp.BSL <- isolate(input$filter1)
    inp.loc <- isolate(input$filter2)
    if (inp.BSL=='' | inp.loc=='') return()

    # BSL switch
    selection <-switch(inp.BSL
                       , A = "A"
                       , B = "B"
                       ) 
    # Location switch    
    selection2 <-switch(inp.loc
                       , C = "C"
                       , D = "D"
                       )

    # subset based on selection
    Subgeodata <- subset(geodata, BSL == selection & Position.Location == selection2)

    # browser()
    # aggregate by postcode
    Subgeodata <- Subgeodata[1:2] #no longer need other columns
    AggSubGdata <- aggregate(. ~ Postcode, data=Subgeodata, FUN=sum)
    write.csv(AggSubGdata
              , file = "solution.csv"
              , row.names=F
    )
  })
})
```

and a short analysis of your code:

1. The main reason `geodatasetInput` does not start at all is because it is a `reactive()` expression. `reactive()` is evaluated only when it is called by something else like `renderTable()` in the answer of @pops. If you want it to be executed by itself, it should be `observe()`.
2. It might be a good idea to have `input$generateButton` in the beginning of your observe() expression.
3. In `ui.R`, you call a numeric input field `filter1`, but you try to obtain its value as `input$BSL` from `server.R`; the same is true for `filter2`.
4. As you want `geodataSetInput` to be triggered only on `generateButton`, all other `input$` and reactive expressions withing `geodataSetInput` should be isolated with `isolate()`. On the other hand, there is no need to isolate `write.csv` because this particular function call does not involve any 'dynamic' parameters.

Answer (score 1):

you would need to Render your the table you're subsetting, perhaps someone else can explain why you need this co-dependance. Below is the working example of the way I went to solve it. It will save the solution.csv in the working directory.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
# You can change this directory
setwd("/Users/lukesingham/SOtestApp")
geodata <- read.csv("geodata.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",",stringsAsFactors =FALSE)

ui = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Min. working example - write a csv based on user input'),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("filter1", "First selection:", choices = c("A", "B"),selected = "A"),    
    selectInput("filter2", "Second selection:", choices = c("C", "D"),selected = "C"),
    br(),
    p("Include actionButton to prevent write occuring before user finalises selection"),  
    actionButton("generateButton","Write Data")),mainPanel(tableOutput("test1"))
)

server = function(input, output) {

  geodatasetInput <- reactive({
    if(input$generateButton == 0){return()}

    isolate({ 
      input$generateButton
      test_data <- geodata[geodata$BSL %in% as.character(input$filter1),]
      test_data <- geodata[geodata$Position.Location %in% as.character(input$filter2),]
      test_data <- test_data[,1:2]
      test_data <- aggregate(. ~ Postcode, data=test_data, FUN=sum)
      test_data
    })
    write.csv(test_data,"solution.csv",row.names=F)
  })
  output$test1 <- renderTable({geodatasetInput()})
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```