# reactively writing 2 elemenst to a csv file

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I am trying to write the result the user gets in a dice throw and the time he hits the throw button in a CSV file which i can access later at my own time.

I have borrowed code from the following example([R/Shiny - How to write a .csv reactively including a actionButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854248/r-shiny-how-to-write-a-csv-reactively-including-a-actionbutton)) ,but i am unable to incorporate more than one reactive actions. As in can get the code to write the result to a csv file,but when i call the function to get the start time i get the following error-"Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6949
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)"

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
a<-sample(c(1:6),1,replace=TRUE)

ui = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Min. working example - write a csv based on user input'),
  sidebarPanel(

    p("Include actionButton to prevent write occuring before user finalises selection"),  
    actionButton("generateButton","throw")),mainPanel(tableOutput("test1"))
)

server=(function(input, output) {

  getstart<-function(){

    if (input$runButton == 0) {return()} 
    else{
      v1<-Sys.time()
      g1<-as.character(v1) 
    }
    return(g1)

  }

  time<-getstart()
  b<-as.character(time)

  geodatasetInput <- observe({

    # Execute selections on data upon button-press
    if(input$generateButton == 0) {return()}
     else{

    AggSubGdata <- df
    write.csv(AggSubGdata
              , file = "solution21.csv"
              , row.names=F
    )
     }
  })
  output$test1<-renderText({
    if(input$generateButton==0){return(NULL)}
     else{
    a
     }
  })
})

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

I tried to put the getstart() function outside the shiny body and trigged to trigger it with a global variable . I tried to assign the value to this global variable from the use of the actionbuttion by using <<- operator,but the attempt did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer .I have a complete solution called CSV Comp Framework.
what he does:
is a Database System Manager (Relational using CQL ,in CSV file Format) + CGI server.
works on Linux,windows e windows ce.
the desktop version is free ( linux and windows ).html example:

```
    <html>
        <h1>Write your name and phone number with CSV Comp Framework</h1>
        <form action='http://server/cgi-bin/executa/default?'>
        Name:<br>
        <input type='text' name='ID-name'></a></p>

        Phone number:<br>
        <input type='text' name='ID-phone'></a></p>
        <!--CQL is another Query Language before Cassandra exists-->

        <input type='submit' name='YOUR_SCRIPT.cql'></a></p>
         </form>
        </html>

//the "YOUR_SCRIPT.cql" script CQL in cgi-bin
  {
   server-path/htdocs/YOUR_AGENDA;
   @adicionar;
   (ID-name;ID-phone);
   0;
   0;
   0;
   query=0;
   destino=0
   }
```

So,you can use with relationship from desktop to server and vice versa